# Q basis for splitting field

Tags: field-theory, extension-field, cyclotomic-polynomials, splitting-field

I have the following field theory question: I am given this polynomial
$ x^5-5 $ for which I am supposed to find a basis for the splitting field over Q all I can determine in this regard is that it has order 20 I was never really taught how to find something like a basis for a cyclotomic field all I know is that the splitting field is $ Q(\sqrt{5},\zeta_5) $ Could you please help me find a Q basis and explain to me how to do it please? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

You can use  what is called a “primitive element” of K for what you can take an element x such that the images of x by the 20 Q-automorfisms of K (splitting field) be distinct. You can verify that the simple sum of your elements satisfy this condition.